# How can you use COUNT(DISTINCT...) when one of the values is the result of a SELECT statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL statement that returns rows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT wp_w2bw2c_event.venue_id, 
    (SELECT MIN(begin_date)     
        FROM wp_w2bw2c_event_detail 
        WHERE wp_w2bw2c_event_detail.event_id = wp_w2bw2c_event.id) 
    as begin_date, 
    wp_w2bw2c_event.id as event_id 
    FROM wp_w2bw2c_event 
    INNER JOIN wp_w2bw2c_venue 
    ON wp_w2bw2c_venue.id = wp_w2bw2c_event.venue_id 
    INNER JOIN wp_w2bw2c_event_detail 
    ON wp_w2bw2c_event_detail.event_id = wp_w2bw2c_event.id 
    WHERE wp_w2bw2c_venue.venue_name LIKE '%ironworks%' 
    OR artist_name LIKE '%ironworks%' 
    OR event_title LIKE '%ironworks%' 
    OR event_detail_title LIKE '%ironworks%' 
    ORDER BY wp_w2bw2c_event.venue_id, begin_date, event_id
```

If I try and use the `COUNT` function to just count the number of rows, I get a SQL database error

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT wp_w2bw2c_event.venue_id, 
    (SELECT MIN(begin_date)     
        FROM wp_w2bw2c_event_detail 
        WHERE wp_w2bw2c_event_detail.event_id = wp_w2bw2c_event.id) 
    as begin_date, 
    wp_w2bw2c_event.id as event_id) 
    FROM wp_w2bw2c_event 
    INNER JOIN wp_w2bw2c_venue 
    ON wp_w2bw2c_venue.id = wp_w2bw2c_event.venue_id 
    INNER JOIN wp_w2bw2c_event_detail 
    ON wp_w2bw2c_event_detail.event_id = wp_w2bw2c_event.id 
    WHERE wp_w2bw2c_venue.venue_name LIKE '%ironworks%' 
    OR artist_name LIKE '%ironworks%' 
    OR event_title LIKE '%ironworks%' 
    OR event_detail_title LIKE '%ironworks%' 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'as begin_date, 
    wp_w2bw2c_event.id as event_id 
    FROM wp_w2bw2c_event 
    INNE' at line 5
```

How can I change the SQL so that `COUNT(DISTINCT...` works with the result of a SELECT?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

Your query returns distinct rows. So all you have to do is count the results from that query:

```
select count(*) from (your query) q;
```

Comment: I tried that and got the error `#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias`. Even when I aliased all the table names I still received that error.

Comment: Besides, this query would be completely redundant

Comment: Had a formatting error. This method seems to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you are attempting is unnecessarily complicated.  What is wrong with the simple way?

```
select venueId
, min(begin_date) minBeginDate
from etc
where whatever
group by venueId
```

This will give you distinct values.

Comment: You have no idea what you are talking about. If you have nothing to add, stay off the line.